# GROUP BY doesn't work with a subquery

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following query

```
SELECT `id` FROM `TableA` WHERE `color` LIKE '%red%' 
AND `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `TableB` GROUP BY `option`)
```

When I run this query, I get the same result as if I ran

```
SELECT `id` FROM `TableA` WHERE `color` LIKE '%red%' 
AND `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `TableB`)
```

I get over 400 records. However, if I run

```
SELECT `id` FROM `TableB` GROUP BY `option`
```

I get 18 records.

I haven't run this query in a while, but I remember it was working. The only change that happened between the last time I ran it and now is that I upgraded from MySQL 5.5 (or 5.6) to MariaDB 10.1. Any idea why it stopped working?

Here is the SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/440224/1

It returns records with the IDs 1,2 and 3 even though 1 and 2 have the same value in `TableB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is related  to the new version on mysql  that don't allow an improper use of group by ..

In your query you are using a group by without an aggregation function and this is not more allowed

instead of the flat

```
SELECT `id` FROM `TableA` WHERE `color` LIKE '%red%' 
AND `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `TableB` GROUP BY `option`)
```

you should us an aggegation function for retrive the id eg:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `TableA` WHERE `color` LIKE '%red%' 
AND `id` IN (SELECT min(`id`) FROM `TableB` GROUP BY `option`)
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid  correct  ..my answer  was related  closely to question provided ..anyway the problem with group by remain the same